# How to improve CGridView's performance in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am just curious about the performance of CGridView in Yii Framework. I built a simple app with Yii. on a Model's admin page, simply listing all records, with pagination (30/page) , and custom sorting, which is working great so far.

But I find that it takes 4-5 seconds to render the CGridView. Is it normal to render a 30 records page in 4-5 secs? I kind of feel it's slow! Because it's not a complicated table, with only 8 columns. And the SQL query generated is running fast (done in 2-3 ms), although including a few relations.

I googled a lot on the optimization, and found this official document: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.performance

Focus on the CGridView problem, I tried to use cache, and find [COutputCache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/COutputCache) which is a really good helper.

My practice is add COutputCache in the filter() function of the Controller:

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        array(  'COutputCache+admin,_lists',   'duration' => 600,'varyByParam'=>array('sort','page'),     ),
    );
}
```

You could add normal view pages and also the partial page, set the expire time in seconds, and tell Yii which parameter to detect the cache change.

And this helps a lot when you re-visit the page, including sorting and paging. Low down page render time to **40-50 ms** which is awesome!

But I haven't found a good way to speed up the first time rendering. Do you have any good suggestions?

Comment: 4-5 seconds seems really long for CGridView. Are you using the "standard" Gii CRUD generated gridview or have you modified it much?

Comment: Take a look at yii logs to see what part of your code is slow. Make sure you use `renderPartial` for grid view ajax requests. And you could try `yiibooster` json grid view.

Comment: A good look at the profiling summary is where I'd start, the initial SQL may seem small, but 3 relations on that gives you and extra 90 queries to run on a 30 record page.

Comment: As soju said, it's really important to use `renderPartial` beacause if you don't the ajax call will return the whole page. You should put the CGridView in its own view and render only it.
Then You also should try eager loading while you load the relations, because if you don't the code could be executing 90 queries as Paystey said.

Comment: You can also look at http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/json-grid.html.

Comment: @eskimo mostly standard, just custom sorting header which doesn't effect the speed.

Comment: @soju I did use `renderPartial` dynamically. use `render` in normal request,  `renderPartial` in ajax request(sorting, paging). `$render=Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest ? 'renderPartial' : 'render';
  
  $this->$render('admin',array(
   'model'=>$model,   
  ));`

Comment: @Paystey I am returning a CArrayDataProvider as the data source of CGridView, and the CArrayDataProvider is returned really fast in ms. so I think we don't need to worry about the SQL queries.

Comment: I am digging the Framework's source code, CGridView->renderTableBody()  takes 95% of the page render time. Will dig deep.

Comment: it's most definitely the data, that is adding up the time. show the query, and your array dataprovider code. if you are looking at renderTableBody, the first call is to getData of dataprovider, this is where it takes time.

Comment: @JinzhaoHuo if you're using an array data provider does that mean your doing the query yourself? If so would it be worth using CSqlDataProvider? Things like ordering and pagination can be made much more efficient if done on the query. If you're already doing this then ignore me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case reason of low performance is use html type for data columns.

Answer (score 0):

First, display your log in your webpage to see what is going on so we can help.

Second, no, it is not normal. ¿What server are you on? Are you using CActiveRecord relations? how many? maybe the answer is just to use CDbCriteria.with to do not lazy load the related tables.

Answer (score 0):

You´ve got to check the sorting, whenever the sorting field is not an index you will get slow results from the query built by Yii